# FLutter File initialization failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-futurebuilder

I created an app to pick an image from the gallery and display it. I have created a File called "image" as mentioned below.

```
File image;
```

Then I created a function to pick the image as follow

```
void _pickImageCamera() async {
final picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final pickedImageFile = File(image.path);
setState(() {
  image = pickedImageFile;
});
```

}

The app doesnt run and shows the following error

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building Pick(dirty, state: _PickState#07f0f):
LateInitializationError: Field 'image' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Pick
lib\main.dart:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _PickState.image (package:clone_insta/Picker.dart)
package:clone_insta/Picker.dart:1
#1      _PickState.build
package:clone_insta/Picker.dart:39
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4691
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
```

This is where I call and display the image

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: _pickImageCamera,
        child: Text("Pick"),
      ),
      image != (null)
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 400,
              width: 100,
              child: Image.file(image),
            )
          : Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 400,
              width: 100,
              child: Text("No data"),
            )
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: try put _pickImageCamera() in initState

Comment: still the same error shows

Comment: Can you put where are you calling _pickImageCamera() into your post? I can't see it

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the your image variable with some image you want your user to see when they open the app, you can use shared_preferences to update the value of the image so when the user reopens the app they see the last image they picked.

If you want to use sharedpreferences, make sure to check is the userImage contains some value and if it does use that path to load the image the user picked last.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late File image = File('your initial file');
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  void _pickImageCamera() async {
    final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {
      image = pickedImageFile;
    });
    prefs.setString('stringValue', "the path to the new image");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: MyApp._title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(MyApp._title)),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _pickImageCamera,
              child: Text("Pick"),
            ),
            image != (null)
                ? Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Image.file(image),
                  )
                : Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Text("No data"),
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: TextButton(
            onPressed: _pickImageCamera,
            child: Text("Pick"),
          ),

Comment: This is how i  called the function

Comment: Can you explain to me how?

Comment: Sure, to make a variable Nullable you just add  a ? after the type of your variable, in your case i would be "File? image;"

Comment: I did and didn't work. shows the same error

Comment: i just saw you updated your post, you are calling image as a child of the container, but when you build the app image has nothing, so, even if you make it nullable, the app expects it to have a value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233518/discussion-between-learnado-and-jaime-ortiz).

Answer (score 2):

Just Change

```
late File image;
```

to

```
var image;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it's Simply helped me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to change

from this: `File image;`

to this: `var image;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).